# RGB to CMYK equivalent color

Tags: color, cmyk

TeXnicians, How to convert RGB to equivalent CMYK color value from RGB color values?
Please find MWE file as follows:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage{color,}

\definecolor{rgbcolor}{rgb}{0.686,0.059,0.569}
%\definecolor{cmykcolor}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0}


\begin{document}
\textcolor{rgbcolor}{This is RGB color}

%\textcolor{cmykcolor}{This is Equivalent for converted RGB to CMYK color}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The xcolor package has conversion commands.

Comment: Please show the page number or macros for conversion

Comment: @UlrikeFischer you posted first: I can remove my answer.

Comment: @NBur  there's no need to remove it. It's fine.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580033/87678

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xcolor` package

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{rgbcolor}{rgb}{0.686,0.059,0.569} %\definecolor{cmykcolor}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0}
\convertcolorspec{named}{rgbcolor}{cmyk}\tmp
\definecolor{cmykcolor}{cmyk}{\tmp}
\begin{document}
    \textcolor{rgbcolor}{This is RGB color}

    \textcolor{cmykcolor}{This is Equivalent for converted RGB to CMYK color}.
    The computed values are: \tmp.
\end{document}
```

Comment: We created PDF file rgbcolor and cmykcolor shows complete different color.

Comment: Sure! https://adventureswithart.com/convert-rgb-to-cmyk/

Comment: Above link show near same, but in PDFLaTeX shows complete different color

Comment: I need values of CMYK

Comment: Just print the `\tmp` content: `Value of CMYK is \tmp`

Comment: You should read the `xcolor` documentation, subsection 6.3.1 p. 47 and subsection 6.3.2 p. 50 (in version 2.12). It seems you can adjust some parameters…

Comment: Thank you, I got the solution.

Comment: @RajeshN how did you solve your problem?